# Svelte equivalent of React's props.children?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

I haven't found this feature anywhere in svelte 3..
I want it to be something like this..

App.svelte

```html
<Error>
   <p>Can't connect to the server!</p>
</Error>`
```

Error.svelte

```html
<div>{props.children}</div>
```

I want App.svelte to show:

```html
<div><p>Can't connect to the server!</p></div>
```

I only know how to do this with React's props.children.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [slot](https://alligator.io/svelte/slots/). It is a component provided by svelte. You can use it inside your component. Whatever is passed to component will be rendered in place of slot

Try this in your error.svelte

```
<div>
    <slot />
</div>
```

Comment: It is the standard name from the web-components standard - so good on svelte to use this name/approach.

Comment: In case you want multiple children you can use [named slots](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/named-slots)
`<slot name="nameOfTheSlot" />`